# carbone js usage with react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pdf-generation

I was trying to use Carbone js with react project in this way

```
const carbone = require("carbone");
const fs = require("fs");
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
....
```

my SAVE PDF button function

```
onClick() {
    // Data to inject
    var data = {
      firstname: "John",
      lastname: "Doe",
    };

    // Generate a report using the sample template provided by carbone module
    // This LibreOffice template contains "Hello {d.firstname} {d.lastname} !"
    // Of course, you can create your own templates!
    carbone.render(
      "./node_modules/carbone/examples/simple.odt",
      data,
      function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        // write the result
        fs.writeFileSync("result.pdf", result);
      }
    );
  }
```

then I got this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

[image]

I just need to send user a pdf file of which he had filled the legal document form 
like this [flashlawyer app](https://flashlawyer.com/doc/boat-bill-of-sale/modify/-M6CrR3O71kbaBHRY_tV)
Your little advice is too much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

You can't use Carbone directly in your React app, you'll need a server with Carbone installed and consume the HTTP API.

## Ok, then now ?

If you don't want to build your own Carbone server, you can use the official one as you can read [in the documentation](https://carbone.io/api-reference.html). This service has a free plan (with 100 renders per month), and has a great support. Feel free to contact the Carbone team if you need some help, they're nice people :)